# Disabling Operating System TCP Management

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, tcpip

Is there a way to disable TCP state management of OS, for example on a specific port, or on another ip or if not, disabling the whole tcp management and managing it in an application with root access?

I need a linux/mac based solution but windows-based solutions can also help.

### More info:

I want to make a special proxy, a send relay actually, which manipulates the packet before delivering it to the destination in a way that the original sender gets the answer directly. Sending is easy but the OS of the final receiver rejects the packet and terminates the semi-connection.

Comment: You can do this.  It's frequently done for satellite communications links to spoof the ACK before the SYN has actually received the packet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell which of these you are trying to accomplish:

You want to intercept traffic before it gets handed to the application that owns the socket?

Add relevant rules to the firewall tables sending the packet to a ULOG target and handle it in your userspace code that way. Look at the `iptables` manpage and search for ULOG for details.

You want to send crafted packets out on the network hand-crafting parameters such as source MAC/IP/whatever?

You need root permissions to do this and you can do so using a raw socket. Python's [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) is an easy way of doing so.

Comment: The RST packets were my problem. I used this command:

  sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -s MYIP -p tcp --sport MYPORT -j DROP